# How to find all bitmask combinations given i subsequent values can be "0", j can be "1"?

Tags: c++, math, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, bitmask

**Input.**
I have a bit array sized `n` and two integers, `1<=i<=n` and `0<=j<=n`.
`i` indicates the maximum of subsequent numbers that can be `0`. `j` indicates the maximum of subsequent numbers that can be `1`.

**Desired Output**
I search for a method that returns all possible bit arrays sized `n` that fulfill these constraints.

Just looping through all array combinations (first without constraints) would result in exponential time. (Especially if `i/j>>1`. I suppose you can do better).
How can I effectively find those bitmask combinations?

**Example**
Input: `i = 1`, `j = 2`, `n = 3`

Result: Possible arrays are `[0,1,0], [1,0,1],[1,1,0],[0,1,1]`.

Comment: What is ´i´ and ´j´ for 100111 and 011100?

Comment: With a recursive formulation, you can prune much of the search space (any time the recursive call would have either `i` or `j` negative, you can prune)

Comment: For 100111, i=>2 and j>=3.
For 011100, i=>2 and j>=3.
(i and j denote the maximum of the same subsequent digits. The input consists of two i,j and array size n.)

Comment: @BenVoigt Could it also be made with dynamic programming then? (As the first calculation of k bits are also possible in other combinations?)

Comment: @CanBeChangedLater.Hopefully: Yes, that's a good observation.  Or use divide and conquer: instead of working from one end of the string toward the other, cut it in half, build sets of all possible lead combinations, and do the Cartesian product against another set containing all tail combinations.

Comment: Are `i` and `j` maximum values or must they be observed? I.e. is the bit mask `1010101` valid for `i=j=2`?

Comment: Yes, the bit mask would be valid, they are the maximum values. I added an example for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is nice problem for dynamic programming solution. It is enough to have method that returns number of strings starting with given digit (0 or 1) with given length. Than number of digits of length `n` is sum of strings starting with 0 and starting with 1.

Simple python solution with memoization is:

```
_c = {}  # Cache

def C(d, n, ij):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    if (d, n) not in _c:
        _c[(d, n)] = sum(C(1-d, n-x, ij) for x in xrange(1, min(ij[d], n)+1))
    return _c[(d, n)]

def B(n, i, j):
    ij = [i, j]   # Easier to index
    _c.clear()    # Clears cache
    return C(0, n, ij) + C(1, n, ij)

print B(3, 1, 2)
print B(300, 10, 20)
```

Result is:

```
4
1896835555769011113367758506440713303464223490691007178590554687025004528364990337945924158
```

Since value for given digit and length depends on values of opposite digit and length less than given length, solution can be also obtained by calculating values increasingly by length. Python solution:

```
def D(n, i, j):
    c0 = [1]  # Initialize arrays
    c1 = [1]
    for x in xrange(1, n+1):  # For each next digit calculate value
        c0.append(sum(c1[x-y] for y in xrange(1, min(i, x)+1)))
        c1.append(sum(c0[x-y] for y in xrange(1, min(j, x)+1)))
    return c0[-1] + c1[-1]  # Sum strings starting of length n with 0 and 1

print D(3, 1, 2)
print D(300, 10, 20)
```

Later approach is easier to implement in C++.